# A bug with `cycle` and `rectangle` of TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf

In the code below, after drawing a rectangle, `cycle` does not come back to the initial point `(-1,-1)` of the path. Is it a bug?

Let me be clear: first our pen at (-1,-1) the initial point

```
\draw[red] (-1,-1) node{x};
```

then the pen move to (1,1)

```
\draw[red] (-1,-1) node{x} rectangle (1,1) node{y};
```

however pen does not move to the initial point with

```
\draw[red] (-1,-1) node{x} rectangle (1,1) node{y}--cycle;
```

Note that it work well with other path operations such as `parabola`, `arc`, `to`, .... I am using latest version of TikZ on Windows 10.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% cycle works well as usual
\draw[teal] (-1,1) node{a} parabola bend (0,0) (2,4) node{b}--cycle;
\draw[blue] (-1,0) node{m} arc(180:0:1) node{n}--cycle;
\draw[orange] (-2,0) node{p} to[out=80,in=120] (1,4) node{q}--cycle;

% cycle does not come back the initial point (-1,-1) of the path. Is it a bug?
\draw[red] (-1,-1) node{x} rectangle (1,1) node{y}--cycle;
%\draw[red] (-1,-1) node{x} rectangle (1,1) node{y}--(-1,-1);    %<<< work!
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Appendix 1** I came this situation when drawing HSBC's logo.

[image]

**Appendix 2.** I found that `decoration.markings` changes the way TikZ calculate position on the path `rectangle`. With this library loaded, `(A) rectangle (B)` means `(A)--(A|-B)--(B)--(B|-A)--A`, that is: start `pos=0` at A , then go counter-clockwise, reach B at `pos=0.5`, then continuously go counter-clockwise, and back to A again.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[gray!50] (-1,0) grid (5,5);
\draw (0,1) node{start} rectangle (4,4) node{end}
foreach \i in {.1,.2,...,.9} 
{node[pos=\i]{\pgfmathprintnumber{\i}}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{tikzpicture}[markpos/.style={
decoration={markings,mark=at position #1
with {\node[red,scale=.7]{pos=\pgfmathprintnumber{#1}};}
          },
postaction={decorate}}]

\draw[gray!50] (-1,0) grid (5,5);
\foreach \i in {.1,.2,...,.9}{ 
\draw[markpos=\i] (0,1) node{start} rectangle (4,4) node{end};}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Situation is more fun (jump at `pos=0.7` and `pos=0.8`) when using

```
\foreach \i in {.1,.2,...,.9}{ 
\draw[markpos=\i] (0,1) node{start} rectangle (4,4) node{end}--(0,1);}
```

[image]

Comment: Why do you think that?

Comment: @Sigur Because the red does not come back (-1,-1) - the initial point of the path.

Comment: I don't think that the rectangle with the diagonal represents the concept of a closed path coming from the rectangle construction.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think that `rectangle` operation is different from a path to construct a rectangle, that is, a polygonal with 4 edges.

Comment: With TikZ, we build a rectangle knowing the two vertices of one of its diagonals. The path is closed by construction and the use of  `cycle` is useless since closing what is already closed is a nonsense.

Comment: @AndréC From both developer and user (and mathematical) viewpoints, it 's more natural to assign `cycle` with the meaning "come back to the initial point", rather than caring before path is already closed or not.

Comment: What would be the effect of `cycle` if the command `\draw (x,y) rectangle (z,w);` would be equivalent to `\draw (x,y) -- (x,w) -- (z,w) -- (z,y) -- cycle;`?

Comment: In case you are interested: [the source code](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/blob/master/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex#L3322)

Comment: @BlackMild The construction of a rectangle is a macro that has two arguments: the vertices of the diagonals. This macro constructs the two paths that go from one to the other. Thus, the second vertex is in itself the last point of the path.

Comment: So `rectangle` update the initial point? like the way `++` update calculating point? `\draw[red] (-1,-1) node{x} rectangle (1,1) node{y}--(2,2) arc(-90:150:1)--cycle;`

Comment: @BlackMild no, the first vertex of the rectangle is the beginning of the path, the second is its end. You can see this by writing this: `\draw[red] (-1,-1)  rectangle (1,1) node[midway]{a};` the node is placed in the middle of the diagonal.

Comment: @all: I came this situation when drawing HSBC's logo: `\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.3]
\fill[red,even odd rule]
(-1,-1) rectangle (1,1)--(2,0)--(1,-1)--(-1,1)--(-2,0)--(-1,-1);
\path (current bounding box.south) node[below=1mm,inner sep=0]{HSBC};
\end{tikzpicture}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not necessarily agree with the comments but think you have sort of a point (+1). To see why, let's look at what

```
\draw[red] (-1,-3) node{x} rectangle (1,-1) node{y}
foreach \X in {0,0.2,...,1} {node[pos=\X]{\pgfmathprintnumber{\X}}};
```

produces:

[image]

That is, there *is* a path with `pos=0` the first corner and `pos=1` the second corner of the rectangle. This can be exploited, e.g.

```
\newcommand{\RectCycle}{ coordinate[pos=0] (aux) -- (aux)}    
\draw[red] (-1,-6) node{x} rectangle (1,-4) node{y} \RectCycle;
```

yields

[image]

This seems to be what you are looking for. Redefining the rectangle path construction in `tikz.code.tex` is arguably too dangerous.

Here is a complete example.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% cycle works well as usual
\draw[teal] (-1,1) node{a} parabola bend (0,0) (2,4) node{b}--cycle;
\draw[blue] (-1,0) node{m} arc(180:0:1) node{n}--cycle;
\draw[orange] (-2,0) node{p} to[out=80,in=120] (1,4) node{q}--cycle;

% cycle does not come back the initial point (-1,-1) of the path. Is it a bug?
\draw[red] (-1,-3) node{x} rectangle (1,-1) node{y}
foreach \X in {0,0.2,...,1} {node[pos=\X]{\pgfmathprintnumber{\X}}};

\newcommand{\RectCycle}{ coordinate[pos=0] (aux) -- (aux)}

\draw[red] (-1,-6) node{x} rectangle (1,-4) node{y} \RectCycle;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh, it's strange! by seeing `pos`, I realize that `rectangle` does make a diagonal path: `pos=0` for the initial point, `pos=1` for the last point of the current path (name it R); and then, when we extend that path, then the initial point of the whole path now is  the last point of the path R.

Comment: @BlackMild I am not sure I understand your point but the real difference is that the other path constructions you list talk to the cycle expander, e.g. for the cosine path construction one has `\def\tikz@cosine s{\tikz@cycle@expander{\tikz@scan@one@point\tikz@@cosine}}`. This is not true for the rectangle path construction (nor for circle). However, I feel that adding this to rectangle may do too much harm in existing codes.

Comment: Luckily, after `circle`, the initial and last points (`pos=0` and `pos=1`) are coincident. I like TikZ due to its natural syntax: when we can draw as if we have a pen, and just follow the head of the pen. However, for some technical reason (I am not enough background at TeX programming to see why) it's acceptable when adding an special case for `rectangle`.

Comment: @BlackMild Yes, but I would like to argue that it is not too much hassle to use the above `\newcommand` or something analogous.

Comment: @Schodinger's cat: Sure! `\RectCycle` command is a quick way! Because for `rectangle`, we do not use diagonal path often (as far as I experienced), it's better to put that command in the coming update of TikZ IMHO.

Comment: @SC: please have a look at Appendix of the question.